# The image display in iOS webview is blurry but the same image for imageview is clear

Tags: ios, image, webview, blurry

I experienced this problem for weeks for the app we are developing. Following are the HTML code I use in iOS webview:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
<style>
  body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
  img {width:100%; height:auto; margin:0; padding: 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src='http://hostname/image.jpg' />
</body>
</html>
```

I googled it and sb said that we should use multiple images for different devices: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html and [Serving non-Retina and Retina displays with one code base: framework for scaling layouts and assets for HTML5 apps on iPhones or iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733223/serving-non-retina-and-retina-displays-with-one-code-base-framework-for-scaling/7736803#7736803) .

**But the question is**: why when I switch to use imageview, the same image displays well without blurry?

I also tried the android solution: [Android local image displayed via webview is blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514435/android-local-image-displayed-via-webview-is-blurry/22079820#22079820) but it does not work for iOS.